# Converting PDF files to set of PNG images in J2ME

Tags: pdf, java-me, png

I wish to convert a PDF file into set of PNG images.I came across a large number of Java libraries,but none of them are compatible with J2ME.

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To properly open a [`PDF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) a library must use some form of [`Random Access File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) because of the xref table at the end of the file. This sort of file connection is not available in Java ME.

What a library can do in Java ME is to fully load the PDF to memory, which is highly dependent on the file size and the handset memory available.

You better create a Web Service to receive your PDF and return the PNG images from it.